# How to build a 2 Column (Fixed - Fluid) Layout with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, fluid-layout

Is it possible to create a 2 Column Layout (Fixed - Fluid) Layout ( http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-21-fixed-fluid/) with Twitter Bootstrap (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)?

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: The Sidebar and the Content column must have the same height (min-height: 100%).

Comment: The Sidebar will be static (for a naviagtion) and the height of the content column will be various. That means each of them could be the longer column.

Comment: I have used jquery to set the height to 100%, but i prefer a css solution: http://50.57.127.196/bootstrap/fluid.html
(The CSS Syntax isn`t pretty nice and the right white space bugs me)

Comment: What am I missing here? The question seems totally valid. The Bootstrap documentation provides classes for .container or .container-fluid, and .row or .row-fluid, that both seem to be designed to wrap a series of exclusively fixed, or exclusively fluid  columns.

Comment: The accepted answer seems to be fluid-fluid. Here is an answer that is actually fixed-fluid: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9739345/237091

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**- Another Update -**

***Since Twitter Bootstrap version 2.0 - which saw the removal of the `.container-fluid` class - it has not been possible to implement a two column fixed-fluid layout using just the bootstrap classes - however I have updated my answer to include some small CSS changes that can be made in your own CSS code that will make this possible***

It is possible to implement a fixed-fluid structure using the CSS found below and *slightly* modified HTML code taken from the Twitter Bootstrap **[Scaffolding : layouts](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#layouts)** documentation page:

#### HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid fill">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="fixed">  <!-- we want this div to be fixed width -->
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="hero-unit filler">  <!-- we have removed spanX class -->
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
/* CSS for fixed-fluid layout */

.fixed {
    width: 150px;  /* the fixed width required */
    float: left;
}

.fixed + div {
     margin-left: 150px;  /* must match the fixed width in the .fixed class */
     overflow: hidden;
}


/* CSS to ensure sidebar and content are same height (optional) */

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.fill { 
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.filler:after{
    background-color:inherit;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin:inherit;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: inherit;
    z-index: -1;  
}
```

I have kept the answer below - even though the edit to support 2.0 made it a fluid-fluid solution - as it explains the concepts behind making the sidebar and content the same height *(a significant part of the askers question as identified in the comments)*

---

## Important

### Answer below is fluid-fluid

**Update**
***As pointed out by @JasonCapriotti in the comments, the original answer to this question (created for v1.0) did not work in Bootstrap 2.0. For this reason, I have updated the answer to support Bootstrap 2.0***

To ensure that the main content fills at least 100% of the screen height, we need to set the height of the `html` and `body` to 100% and create a new css class called `.fill` which has a minimum-height of 100%:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.fill { 
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

We can then add the `.fill` class to any element that we need to take up 100% of the sceen height. In this case we add it to the first div:

```
<div class="container-fluid fill">
    ...
</div>
```

To ensure that the Sidebar and the Content columns have the same height is very difficult and unnecessary. Instead we can use the `::after` pseudo selector to add a `filler` element that will give the illusion that the two columns have the same height:

```
.filler::after {
    background-color: inherit;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: inherit;
    z-index: -1;  
}
```

To make sure that the `.filler` element is positioned relatively to the `.fill` element we need to add `position: relative` to `.fill`:

```
.fill { 
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

And finally add the `.filler` style to the HTML:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid fill">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="span9 hero-unit filler">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Notes**

- If you need the element on the left of the page to be the filler then you need to change `right: 0` to `left: 0`.

Comment: I'm confused, I thought you asked for fixed-fluid, not fluid-fluid?  (25%-75% I think is Bootstrap's example)

Comment: I just want to point out that while this code was probably great at the time, it does not work in Bootstrap 2.

Comment: unfortunately this solution doesn't work when you make the sidebar the filler: http://jsfiddle.net/RaHyh/34/

Comment: @BalaClark The idea is that you make the back ground color of the page and the side bar the same colour and then the content of the page becomes the filler. However, if you just want to just make the sidebar fill the screen then change `right: 0;` to `left: 0` - although you will run into issues with padding which you will have to fix (this case can be resolved by changing `left` to the same as your `padding-left` which in this scenario is 20px): http://jsfiddle.net/RaHyh/38/

Comment: I followed the instructions, and it works great! But I'm trying to change the color of the sidebar, but I can't figure out how. Everything I try ends up with changing much more than I want. Is there an fix for this?

Comment: @HenrikSkogmo if you can knock up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your problem then I will take a look

Comment: I'm just as confused as @mikemike: the two working examples linked to in this answer both appear to be fluid-fluid, not fixed-fluid?

Comment: Yeah, both those examples are fluid-fluid, not fixed-fluid.

Comment: Is it not possible to get a fixed fluid solution then?

Comment: the below answer is the correct use of fix - fluid, this example is fluid - fluid

Comment: Please down-vote this answer. It's fluid-fluid and not fixed-fluid as asked.

Comment: The first part of this answer works perfectly out-of-the-box for a fixed-fluid layout: https://jsfiddle.net/Lja1867n/1/

Answer (score 12):

***Update 2018***

**Bootstrap 4**

Now that BS4 is flexbox, the **fixed-fluid** is simple. Just set the width of the fixed column, and use the `.col` class on the fluid column.

```
.sidebar {
    width: 180px;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="sidebar p-2">Fixed width</div>
    <div class="col bg-dark text-white pt-2">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/7LzXiPxo6a

**Bootstrap 3**..

One approach to a **fixed-fluid** layout is using media queries that align with Bootstrap's breakpoints so that you only use the fixed width columns are larger screens and then let the layout stack responsively on smaller screens...

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
  #sidebar {
      min-width: 300px;
      max-width: 300px;
  }
  #main {
      width:calc(100% - 300px);
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Working Bootstrap 3 **Fixed-Fluid** Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/3CfoaYfQdG)</kbd>

**Related Q&A:**
[Fixed width column with a container-fluid in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060117/fixed-width-column-with-a-container-fluid-in-bootstrap)
[How to left column fixed and right scrollable in Bootstrap 4, responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086159/how-to-left-column-fixed-and-right-scrollable-in-bootstrap-4-responsive)

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Is there a way of preventing column swapping while making Browser very small? Thanks

Comment: It works only if the Content div is 'naturally' smaller than the width of (100% - 300px). in my case, the 'natural' size of the content is greater than that and causes the content div to go to the row after the sidebar ends. the bootstrap 3 solution still works, i just used width instead of min and max width.