# height in a fluid layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to design a fluid / responsive web design using bootstrap.  I'm trying to design the layout so that it'll fit in many devices.  My question about setting height to a layout element, such as the header or footer.  I've got it in pixels right now, but I would like to know if I should be using some other form of measurement.

I'm probably over-thinking this, but I'd like to make sure I'm doing this the right way.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting element height in responsive layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432029/setting-element-height-in-responsive-layout)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid setting a `height` whenever possible. You can often get around - and preferably so - using `padding` on the element in question, and/or `margin` values on the element's children.

If you absolutely need to define a height, use `min-height` so that it'll grow as its children take up more vertical space.

Many times people fall back to defining static `height` values because the elements are also using `float` and add height to get content flow and backgrounds back. This is rather poor practice and if this is the case you should consider looking into [methods of clearing floats](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

Comment: Perfect answer. To get around, I'd add to `padding`, `margin`: `line-height` and (rarely used) along `display: table: cell` also `border-spacing`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably pixels are the best option if you have a lot different devices. Other measurements to consider:

- **em** (1em equals default font size)
- **%** (of the screen)

Answer (score 0):

em and % is the good solution for fluid / responsive web design.

I will suggest for media query css

```
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

    }
```