# How to make div in grid view be of 90% height of page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want to create grid view, where header contains 10% height of the page and body 90%.

I have tried to adjust this, but body part does not grow when element section on right hand scales.

I want to add elements in right panel in responsive manner.

Is there any good way to organize this?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/q18yzkoz/5/

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:lavender;">
            <div class="header">Header Height should be 10% of the page</div>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-xs-8" style="background-color:lavenderblush; height:100%">Body, Height should be 90% of th page
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
            <!-- 12 repeated rows as below, height should fit in 90% region in responsive manner -->
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
                    <div class="element-box">Item1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
                    <div class="element-box">item2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
                    <div class="element-box">Item3</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
                    <div class="element-box">item4</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
                    <div class="element-box">Item5</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
                    <div class="element-box">item6</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
                    <div class="element-box">Item7</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
                    <div class="element-box">item8</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
                    <div class="element-box">Item9</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
                    <div class="element-box">item10</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
                    <div class="element-box">Item11</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
                    <div class="element-box">item12</div>
                </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a ton of divs that you're not actually using. ALL of those need to explicitly be set to 100% height and also have a wrapper.

Take a look at this pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdOyJp

You have a ton of nested divs. I cut the HTML down to this:

```html
<div class="header">Header Height should be 10% of the page</div>
<div class="content row">
  <div class="col-xs-8" style="background-color:lavenderblush; height:100%">
    Body, Height should be 90% of th page
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
    <!-- all the items... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's what I cut the CSS down to:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.header {
    height : 10%;
    background: teal;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    background: deeppink;
}
```

I set a background on .content so that it would fill the right column. It is a 'faux column' technique but there are many more.

Comment: nice answer, well how elements section in right can be justified as per section height?

Comment: Just get rid of the lavender background on the items and it will APPEAR as if they are the same height.

Answer (score 1):

Neither the BODY (`.col-xs-8`) or the HEADER (`.header`) heights in your code are being recognized. Hence, not only is the body not 90%, but the header is not 10%. The height of the header is simply the height of the content. You can plug in other percentage values and you'll see nothing changes.

This is caused by the multitude of nested containers and various assigned heights in your code, which is a bit confusing and convoluted. However, your mark-up doesn't have to change to accomplish your goal.

Below are my adjustments to your code. I've used inline styles. Eventually, you may want to move these styles to your external stylesheet which may be better for clarity, convenience and maintenance, but I've used inline styles here for demonstration purposes.

First, add a 100% height to your primary `div` container:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="height: 100%;">
```

Second, add a 10% height to your **header** row and include the inline styles from the child `div`.

```
<div class="row" style="height: 10%; background-color:lavender;">

<div class="col-xs-12" //DELETE THIS: style="background-color:lavender;"//>
```

Third, add a 90% height to your **body** row and and include the inline styles from the child `div`.

```
<div class="row" style="height: 90%; background-color: lavenderblush;">

<div class="col-xs-8" //DELETE THIS: style="background-color:lavenderblush; height:100%"//>
```

This does the trick. I gives you 10% for the height and 90% for the body.

http://jsfiddle.net/q18yzkoz/6/

Just keep in mind that the 90% is relative to the parent container (`.container-fluid`) with height 100%, which is relative to the HTML/BODY height 100%. So it extends all the way down to the bottom of the page (which is what your questions asks).

However, if you want the body div to match the right column, adjust the height value of the body row from 90% to ~55%.

http://jsfiddle.net/q18yzkoz/8/

OR, you can reduce the height value of the parent container (`.container-fluid`) to, let's say, 70%, and work from there.

Lastly, you stated in your question:

> Is there any good way to organize this?

There are other ways to create a responsive grid layout that may be more efficient and robust. Here are four methods you may want to consider:

**[Easy Responsive CSS Grid Layouts](http://www.sitepoint.com/easy-responsive-css-grid-layouts/)**

Hope this helps. If you have any questions leave a comment below.

Comment: nice answer. but is that possible to set height of element in `%` values, so that i remains responsive. Rather then giving fixed pixel height

Comment: @nlper, Generally speaking, relative units (percentages, ems) are better for responsive layouts than fixed units (pixels). Here's some more info: http://www.stackoverflow.com/q/9432029/3597276

Comment: @nlper, Setting the width of a layout to be responsive is important. Setting the height of a layout to be responsive may in many cases be less important. For height you may just need a `min-height` or just allow the content to determine the height. Keep in mind that screens adjust horizontally (by width) not vertically (by height), as a vertical scrollbar is considered best practice and a horizontal scrollbar is commonly considered ugly and clunky.