# keeping the depth of a div responsive

Tags: html, css

I have tried adapting this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432029/setting-element-height-in-responsive-layout) and its alistapart links. But I can't get my three blocks in a container to act responsively and maintain their aspect ratio

```
<div class="hpGridTopRow">
  <span class="hpBox lightBlue one">
    <p class="hbBoxesp">New to Restore</p>
  </span>
  <span class="hpBox green two">
    <p class="hbBoxesp">Events</p>
  </span>
  <span class="hpBox midBlue three">
    <p class="hbBoxesp">Talks</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

I need them to arrange themselves to the borders of the hpGridTopRow div so I am using flex - and its working well.

However, the layout has to be responsive - the aspect ratio of the containers needs to stay fixed as their widths change.

Here's the css

```
.hpGridTopRow, 
.hpGridBottomRow {
display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
    height: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:yellow;
}
.hpBox {    
    width:24.18803418803419%;
    text-align:center;
    height:264px;
    height:100%;
}

.hpBox.one {
    width:49.4017094017094%;
}

.lightBlue {
    background:#15b2d2;
}
.green {
    background:#8cc63f;
}
.midBlue {
    background:#6a8aa8;
}    
.hbBoxesp {
    color:#fff;
    margin-top:40px;
}
```

I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maxelcat/94vymj5b/) - as you can the container background shows, but not the actual boxes and said container is behaving responsively.

How can I get the spans to behave properly?

Comment: Ouch, that fiddle just burnt my eyeballs!

Comment: thanks for your helpful comment Pete.

Comment: If you are going to create an example, then do something that we can work with - it took me 30 minutes before I could see properly again.  With it being that bad I just moved on and I'm guessing I'm not the only one - so perhaps that something to keep in mind for future examples.

Comment: well I like the colour, and I have an answer. Just think you should have just moved on... but I will take on board what you say re colours.

Comment: have a sense of humour - someone like it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed those extra colors and simplified the percentages to simplify the code.

The idea is that I've added `position: relative;` to the parent and `position: absolute;` to the children. This ensures that the children positions are bounded to the parent.

I've also added `top: 0; bottom: 0;` to the children, to make the children `span` spans the height as the parent `div`.

Then you have to place the spans in the correct places by using `left` and `right` positioning.

```css
.hpGridTopRow {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
.hpBox {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.hpBox.one {
  width: 50%;
}
.hpBox.two {
  left: 50%;
}
.hpBox.three {
  right: 0;
}
.lightBlue {
  background: #15b2d2;
}
.green {
  background: #8cc63f;
}
.midBlue {
  background: #6a8aa8;
}
.hbBoxesp {
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hpGridTopRow">
  <span class="hpBox lightBlue one">
    <p class="hbBoxesp">New to Restore</p>
  </span>

  <span class="hpBox green two">
    <p class="hbBoxesp">Events</p>
  </span>

  <span class="hpBox midBlue three">
    <p class="hbBoxesp">Talks</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the snippet - and your helpful explanation - looks better. Does this mean that I can't use flex layout because the spacing is now wrong -