# Resize height of a div according to other one

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to resize right div to the height of left one using just CSS?
[My Example](http://jsbin.com/anevor/13/)

I've tried a jQuery approach like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#right").css("height", $("#left").height());
});
```

This approach isn't working well because I have dynamically loaded content in the left div and jQuery approach sometimes miscalculates the height.

I also tried `height:100%` on the right div but it didn't work.

Comment: You can try to bind a function to handle every time height changes the height on the right div gets resized automatically. The thing about `$(document).ready()` is that it is fired only once when the page is finished loading so when you are adding stuff dynamically it might not be causing the event to be fired.

Comment: Why not to use tables? Maybe it is not that cooooooool as blocks layout but it solves the problem without any hacks.

Comment: I'm aware of that, and that isn't the issue. I thought that maybe I don't need to use JavaScript at all if it can be solved using pure CSS.

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8741070/681807

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: If you love hacky way of doing things, @sandeep created [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZBM5/2/) great workaround.

I ended up using [this](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) great jQuery resize plugin. I was hoping there is an easy CSS solution, but the couple of answers in the comments above give me additional browser compatibility issues.
This is what I've done:

```
$("#left").resize(function () {
    $("#right").css("height", $(this).height());
});
```

Answer (score 4):

For this you can use **display:table** property for this. Write like this:

```
#left{
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 425px;
    background-color:#11DD52;
}

#right{
    width:200px;
    background-color:#4477AA;
}
#left, #right{
  display:table-cell;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ZZBM5/

Comment: That's exactly the same as using tables.

Comment: @VisioN no it's not. The markup is radically different. Tables are for displaying tabular data, not for creating layouts.

Comment: @jurgemaister I'm talking about the approach.

Comment: But it's not a table. It's a functionality in which you can use **table** property for the DIV layout

Comment: @jurgemaister Alright. What will you do for IE6,7 (or similar), which do not support `table-cell`?

Comment: @VisioN - I'd redirect them to a form where they can fill in their details and request a print out of the website

Comment: it's supported till IE8 & above.

Comment: `<!--[if lt IE 8]>Go Away<![endif]-->`

Comment: @sandep this works very well, but I need to have support for IE7. Even if I choose to ignore IE7, how can I create that 15px gap (created by margin on the left block) that was there initially?

Comment: @MyHeadHurts That solves the problem in case if you do the website for yourself only :)

Comment: @VisioN it's support IE8 http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3Atable. You have to define HTML5 doctype <!DOCTYPE html>.

Comment: @ttkalec i have created hack for IE7 http://jsfiddle.net/ZZBM5/2/ . I know it's not that good solution but it's work for you.

Comment: @sandeep I actually love your solution. Thank you very much. Very clever thinking :)