# 100% height left sidebar with dynamic right content - Bootstrap + Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a website using Bootstrap and Wordpress. It's a 2-column layout - left sidebar, right content. The right content is dynamic and expands by infinite scroll. I've tried to make the left sidebar 100% height through several techniques but to no avail.

I'd like the sidebar to continue down according to the size of the viewport/height of the right content div.

I've made a bare fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ydPMr/3 but it would be better if you saw what I was talking about on my dev page: http://joshuawalker.koding.com.

Here is the basic structure of my page:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
<div class="navbar-inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="wire-unit hero-fix">
</div>
<div class="sidebar hidden-phone"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to make the sidebar to stretch full height, I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a tricky thing to do. You could accomplish it using jQuery or by sticking the left sidebar inside the div that expands and set the left sidebar's height to 100% and make sure the div it's inside has the position:relative attribute.

Comment: You may find this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8741070/681807

Comment: Thanks for your help, @ MyHeadHurts and @ TrevanHetzal. Will keep your ideas in mind for future developments.

Comment: Here's my fiddle illustrating this! https://jsfiddle.net/magickirbyz/Lyxwumxv/4/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is working fine for me. **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DppA8/32/)**

I set the `min-Height` to `500px`. If you don't want minimum, remove it. It will work according to the `height` of your content in the `content div`. Like this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DppA8/11/)

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar hidden-phone">
    </div>
    <div class="content">


    </div>
</div>
```

and style

```
<style type="text/css" >
    .wrapper
    {
        min-height:100%;
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
        background-color:Black;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .sidebar
    {
        width:20%;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        bottom:0px;
        position:absolute;
        background-color:Aqua;
    }
    .content
    {
        min-height:500px;
        width:80%;
        position:relative;
        background-color:Gray;
        float:right;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the sidebar content go after the content area for SEO purposes?

Comment: @JiewMeng It is working in example perfectly. If it is not working kindly show your code by putting it JSFiddle

Comment: @syedmohsin I believe that JiewMeng means that if the sidebar is larger then the content, the result is strange. http://jsfiddle.net/26y4u12k/

Comment: This works if your rendering a new page but if your dynamically adding things with ajax it will not.