# JavaScript keep sidebar and main element the same height in fluid layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

OK so here's the code I have thus far.

```
var h = document.getElementById("main").offsetHeight;
 document.getElementById("sidebar1").style.height = h + "px";
```

It works in a standard layout, but I also need the height to readjust when the screen size changes the layout for example, going from portrait to landscape on a tablet or in a scenario where infinite scroll is involved, the sidebar height should increase I scroll down the page.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909864/100-height-left-sidebar-with-dynamic-right-content-bootstrap-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works.  Window.onresize should cover the portrait to landscape change.  Window.onscroll should cover the infinite scroll.

```
Window.onresize = resize;
Window.onscroll = resize;

function resize() {
  var node = document.getElementById("main");
  var h = window.getComputedStyle(node,null).height;
  document.getElementById("sidebar1").style.height = h;
};
```

The 'sidebar1' should match 'main'.  The 'getComputedStyle' method is not supported in older IE(<9).

Comment: I gave your code a shot, no luck. The height does not adjust.

Comment: What are you seeing for the variable 'h' when you debug?  Does 'h' show the correct height value?