# Adjust sidebar 100% height of content when height is set already in parent theme in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm basically having the same issue as [100% height left sidebar with dynamic right content - Bootstrap + Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909864/100-height-left-sidebar-with-dynamic-right-content-bootstrap-wordpress).

**BUT** I have created a child-theme (to Oxygen theme) and have this style in my child theme.

```
.content-wrap {position:relative;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    min-height:100%;
}

#sidebar-secondary  {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    width:210px;
    float:right;
    margin:1px 0 0;
    background:#e9e9e9;
    padding:40px 30px 0 30px
}
#content {
    width:500px;
}
```

HTML looks like:

```
<div class="content-wrap">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="sidebar-secondary"></div>
</div>
```

**It should work right?** *But I noticed that height is set to 666px (for #sidebar-secondary) in the parent theme*.  So I would basically like to "disable" the height-property in the parent theme. Is this possible or is there another way to achieve what I want? (To get the sidebar to adjust to 100% of the .content-wrap div)

I would like to override the css-property height in the parent css, but I can't type `height:100% !important;` because it should be `min-height:100%.`

I've also tried with `height:auto !important;` `height: !important` but without no luck.

I can adjust height to be a specific value, like `height:5000px;` but I want to be adjusted 100% and not a specific height.

Comment: look for something like `@media`. There you can adjust nearly everything.

Comment: If you use the developer tools by Chrome you can see something like: `media="all" .mainpage { width: 1024px; height: auto;}`. This is editable in the Style.css in your child-theme. Just write something like that: `@media all {.mainpage {width: 1024px; height: auto;}}`

Comment: Media just tells which media to use it for. #sidebar-secondary {height:auto} and @media all {#sidbar-secondary {height: auto;}} has the same effect, because css applies to screen as default.