# How to make a fixed width column with a container-fluid?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I am trying have a side column on the left with fixed width, and then, on the right a normal Bootstrap `container-fluid`.

Even if the sidebar is not inside the Bootstrap structure, it is OK. I mean it hasn't to be with `col-xx-xx` class.

Whatever I do the main problem is that I don't manage to make the fluid container stays beside the sidebar.

The point is also that if I display to none the sidebar, the fluid container has to use the full width of the page.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A *fixed-fluid* layout is [possible in Bootstrap 3](http://www.bootply.com/PjYIJtOnBV), but now that **Bootstrap 4** is flexbox this layout is much easier. You just need to enable flexbox, and make a few simple adjustments to set the width of your fixed side column `flex: 0 0 300px;`, and then `flex: 1;` on your main column to fill remaining width...

**Bootstrap 4 Alpha 2**
http://codeply.com/go/eAYKvDkiGw

Here's a simpler update for the latest **Bootstrap 4** which is flexbox by default:

**Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6 or Beta**
http://codeply.com/go/V9UQrvLWwz

```
 @media (min-width: 576px) {
     .sidebar {
          max-width: 280px;
     }
 }

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-12 sidebar">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md col-12 main">
            <h2>Main (fluid width...)</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also see: [How to build a 2 Column (Fixed - Fluid) Layout with Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740779/how-to-build-a-2-column-fixed-fluid-layout-with-twitter-bootstrap)

**Update 2018**
[**Bootstrap 4.0.0 example**](https://www.codeply.com/go/eMXpgvmHAc)

Comment: In the first, this layout is 100% correct, but when you add a big content on the bigger column, right column will grow to more that it's width.

Answer (score 1):

Try including your `container-fluid` in a `div` with `margin-left: 200px` (where 200px is your sidebar's width).

Then position your sidebar with `position: absolute` for instance