# Bootstrap 4 Flexbox with Fixed and Flexible Width Columns

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, fixed-width

Using Bootstrap 4 and Flexbox, how would you accomplish a 2 column layout with a fixed-width left column and a flexible right column?

I don't see anything in the docs about how to achieve this... I could do it easily enough using vanilla CSS, but I feel like I should use Bootstrap since I'm already pulling it in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed width column with a container-fluid in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060117/fixed-width-column-with-a-container-fluid-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are looking for:

HTML CODE---->>

```
 <div class="main-container">
  <div class="left">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS------->>

```
.main-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.left{

  min-width:200px;
  max-width:200px;
}
```

Also [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwedep?editors=1100) link.

Comment: This doesn't implement Bootstrap as was requested.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
#sticky-sidebar {
  position:fixed;
  max-width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="col-xs-12" id="sticky-sidebar">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8" id="main">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div
```

Comment: Not a sticky sidebar, a "fixed and flexible width" column. eg. Left column being 200px, right column takes 100% of the remaining container's width. Hence the desire for using Flexbox.

Comment: It's not working. The left column doesn't keep its width while resizing Browser.